# iPhone USB detection delay on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, itunes, iphone

When I connect my iPhone 4 to my Windows 7 PC via USB, there is a long delay before it actually gets detected. I haven't timed it, but sometimes I have to wait up to a minute before I hear the Windows USB connection sound and it shows up in iTunes. It used to make the sound instantly. Other USB devices, like webcams and USB sticks, are detected instantly as usual. What is happening?

Comment: My 3GS regularly has a 10/20s delay when being plugged in... Without iTunes open, i mean the time before the phone registers and the machine detects :)

Answer (score 0):

is it possible you disabled any of the apple services?  start/run type "services.msc" and look at services that begin with apple and see if any are disabled.

Comment: Apple Mobile Device service is started.